# Python. Cannot make a request to simple site api. Flask and requests

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to create simple API for my site. I created the route with flask:

```
@api.route('/api/rate&message_id=<message_id>&performer=<performer_login>', methods=['POST'])
def api_rate_msg(message_id, performer_login):
    print("RATE API ", message_id, ' ', performer_id)
    return 400
```

`print(...)` function don't execute...
I use `flask-socketio` to communicate between client and server.
I send json from client and process it with:

```
@socket.on('rate')
def handle_rate(data):
    print(data)
    payload = {'message_id':data['message_id'], 'performer':data['performer']}
    r = requests.post('/api/rate', params=payload)
    print (r.status_code)
```

Note, that `data` variable is sending from client and is correct(I've checked it).
`print(r.status_code)` don't exec too... 
Where I'm wrong? 
Please, sorry for my bad english :(
This api function must increase rate of message, which stored in mongodb, if interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `&message_id=<message_id>&performer=<performer_login>` in your route string. Instead, get these arguments from `request.args`.

Try it:

```
from flask import request

...

@api.route('/api/rate', methods=['POST'])
def api_rate_msg():
    print(request.args)
    return ''
```

I've tested it with httpie:

```
$ http -v POST :5000/api/rate message_id==123 performer_login==foo
POST /api/rate?message_id=123&performer_login=foo HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.8

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 13:54:40 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.11 Python/2.7.13
```

And from flask's log:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('message_id', u'123'), ('performer_login', u'foo')])
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2017 22:54:40] "POST /api/rate?message_id=123&performer_login=foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Hm... But it is don't work for me(. Code in `api_rate_msg()` don't work. I think, that something wrong with my requests code.

Comment: Test your api like me with httpie or curl so that you could know where's wrong.

Comment: Hmm.. Is your server located outside, not in your local network?

Comment: lol, it's magically solved! I was unable to run `http` becouse dependency error. I uninstall requests and setup it again. Now it's work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below part from your api route

```
&message_id=<message_id>&performer=<performer_login
```

This is not required in POST request. It helps in GET requests. API call in request is not matching the route definition and therefore you have the current problem

Comment: I've do that, but still nothing changed. :( 
Also, I was changed `payload=...` to `payload = {'message_id':data['message_id'], 'performer_login':data['performer']}`, in `handle_rate` but still nothing.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I cannot rate you, becouse my reputation is so low.